# Excel Query (QODBC / QuickBooks) Question: Is it possible to query an sp_report (in excel) and have 2 sets of amount columns?

Tags: sql, excel, quickbooks, qodbc

For example, I am querying the trial balance sp_report and would like to have debit/credit columns for the current year and another set of debit/credit columns for the prior year.

Current code is:

> sp_report TrialBalance show AccountType, Label, AccountFullName,
> AccountName, Debit, Credit parameters DateMacro = 'ThisYear'

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating three sheets in an Excel workbook. Sheet 1 for this year and Sheet 2 for the previous year. You can then use Sheet 3 and create a report by combining values from sheets 1 and 2.

Please feel free to contact us should you have any further queries on this issue related to QODBC.

For our first level free support option, you can create a ticket at http://support.qodbc.com/

For our second level (Remote/Phone/Email) Paid support option, you can create a ticket at http://www.qodbc.com/phsupport.htm